# Better way to extract json map into struct

Tags: json, parsing, elixir

I'm new to elixir and I want to parse a json file. One of the parts is a question answer array of objects.
[
{
"questionId":1,
"question":"Information: Personal Information: First Name",
"answer":"Joe"
},
{
"questionId":3,
"question":"Information: Personal Information: Last Name",
"answer":"Smith"
},
...
]

I know what questionId's I want and I'm going to make a map for 1 = First Name, 2 = Last Name.

But currently I'm doing the following to put the data into the struct.

```
defmodule Student do

  defstruct first_name: nil, last_name: nil, student_number:  nil

  defguard is_first_name(id) when id == 1

  defguard is_last_name(id) when id == 3

  defguard is_student_number(id) when id == 7

end

defmodule AFMC do

  import Student
  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for AFMC.
  """

  @doc """
  Hello world.

  ## Examples

      iex> AFMC.hello
      :world

  """
  def main do
    get_json()
    |> get_outgoing_applications
  end

  def get_json do
    with {:ok, body} <- File.read("./lib/afmc_import.txt"),
          {:ok,body} <- Poison.Parser.parse(body), do: {:ok,body}
  end

  def get_outgoing_applications(map) do
    {:ok,body} = map
    out_application = get_in(body,["outgoingApplications"])


    Enum.at(out_application,0)
    |> get_in(["answers"])
    |> get_person
  end

  def get_person(answers) do

    student = Enum.reduce(answers,%Student{},fn(answer,acc) ->

      if Student.is_first_name(answer["questionId"]) do

        acc = %{acc | first_name: answer["answer"]}

      end

      if Student.is_last_name(answer["questionId"]) do

        acc = %{acc | last_name: answer["answer"]}

      end

      if Student.is_student_number(answer["questionId"]) do

        acc = %{acc | student_number: answer["answer"]}

      end

      acc

    end)

    IO.inspect "test"
    s



  end


end
```

I'm wondering what is a better way to do get_person with out having to do if statements. If I know I will be mapping 1 to questionId 1 in the array of objects. 
The data will then be saved into a DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd store a mapping of id to field name. With that you don't need any `if` inside the reduce. Some pattern matching will also make it unnecessary to do `answer["questionId"]` etc.

```
defmodule Student do
  defstruct first_name: nil, last_name: nil, student_number: nil

  @fields %{
    1 => :first_name,
    3 => :last_name,
    7 => :student_number
  }

  def parse(answers) do
    Enum.reduce(answers, %Student{}, fn %{"questionId" => id, "answer" => answer}, acc ->
      %{acc | @fields[id] => answer}
    end)
  end
end

IO.inspect(
  Student.parse([
    %{"questionId" => 1, "question" => "", "answer" => "Joe"},
    %{"questionId" => 3, "question" => "", "answer" => "Smith"},
    %{"questionId" => 7, "question" => "", "answer" => "123"}
  ])
)
```

Output:

```
%Student{first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Smith", student_number: "123"}
```

Edit: to skip ids not present in the map, change:

```
%{acc | @fields[id] => answer}
```

to:

```
if field = @fields[id], do: %{acc | field => answer}, else: acc
```

Comment: I'm getting a key nil not found error. if the Id is not found it should skip it. Im assuming thats why there is an error.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a fix for that. Let me know if it works!

Comment: works!! thank you, still getting used to pattern matching, I tried doing if Map.has_key but that didn't work, but I think that was because I forgot the else and return the acc.